# Django 1.10: Error Installing django_debug_toolbar

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-debug-toolbar, django-1.10

I'm trying to install [django-debug-toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Whenever I add the middleware in the settings, I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "<project_path>/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "<project_path>/.env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

my settings.py contains all the necessary stuff:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    #...

]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    #....
    #....

]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to upgrade the `django-debug-toolbar` as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068125/3083094) and then add a line in the settings file:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1')
```

to make the toolbar visible

Answer (score 1):

In 1.10, you have to upgrade `django-debug-toolbar` to support `MIDDLEWARE` and `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar --upgrade
```